# Mocha Test Restarting and Failing Second Time

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have a mocha test harness for a node.js api. It stopped working this last week and when I went back to a previous working version it was still having an issue. The mocha tests run the first time all the way through, but at the end they immediately restart and all of them fail. I am using an async function surrounding the tests:

```
before(function () {
// runs before all tests in this block
console.log("--- Starting Test using node: " + process.version + " --- 
");

//Log in the guest user
var request = {
    "email": guestTestor.email,
    "password": guestTestor.password,
    "deviceId": 'web'
};
var url = server + login;
apiCall(request, url, function callback(status, result) {
    if (status === 200 && result.code === 0) {
        console.log("----- Guest Login Succeeded -----");
        guestTestor.token = result.message.token.id;
    } else {
        console.log("----- Guest Login Failed -----");
        guestTestor.token = "";
    }
});
console.log("--- Setup up completed (asyncs will finish shortly) ---");
});

after(async function () {
// runs after all tests in this block
await dbcontrol.deleteDocument(guestTestor.token);

console.log("--- Clean up completed ---");
});
```

This is the output after all the tests pass:

```
--- Clean up completed ---

  Argis Framework Automated Integration Tests
--- Starting Test using node: v8.11.2 ---
--- Setup up completed (asyncs will finish shortly) ---
    User Creation Process
Error in apiCall:Error: only absolute urls are supported
----- Guest Login Failed -----
Error in apiCall:Error: only absolute urls are supported
----- Admin Login Failed -----
Error in apiCall:Error: only absolute urls are supported
----- Argis Login Failed -----
      Create New User Tests
        4) create user should fail on a bad syntax
        5) create user should fail on user already exists
        6) create user successful awaiting verification
        7) create user successful awaiting verification (for expiration test)
        8) login should fail because the user is not validated
        9) create user should fail because esri identity or password is invalid.
        10) create user should succeed with esri identity as the user created
      Validate New User
(node:7100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected 'get user and verification from database' to equal false
    at C:\Users\Malaika\ArgisAPI\test\testing.js:353:79
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:7100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
(node:7100) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tried using different versions of mocha and using --exit. Any ideas why it might be breaking now and why it is restarting at the end?

Comment: If the test fails second time, this likely means that cleanup didn't go well the first time, doesn't it? You're the only person who can check DB. The implementation is specific to your tests and it isn't shown. Code-related issues need https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The problem I see here is that before block is synchronous while the logic inside of it isn't. I'm not sure if this contributes to the problem.

Comment: have you changed versions of/upgraded node.js recently?

Comment: @estus The tests are not actually running the second time because of the errors and the cleanup was successful.

Comment: @hairmot I did upgrade node.js to 8.11.2 recently, but it was working for the first couple of days after I upgraded it.

Comment: If it was working it likely has nothing to do with upgrade. I'm not sure what you mean, but if you have problems on the second run, this means that initial state has changed. Since you don't drop the entire database between runs, a likable reason is that you didn't return it to initial state, i.e. a cleanup failed or was incomplete. Any way, you didn't provide a way to replicate the problem and you're the only person who knows what's going on in your tests.

Comment: @estus I'm more concerned with the fact that the tests restarted on their own than that they failed the second time.

Comment: Ah, I see. It wasn't clear from the question that restarting them wasn't the intention. It depends on your setup why this may happen. The code you've posted contains no clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the server portion of the request url for the apiCall was being overwritten as an object. The tests ran correctly with it as a string and then immediately restarted the tests with the server as an object. I'm still not sure why changing the server made the tests restart, but I took out the faulty line of code making it an object and it works now.